# Ending an assembly procedure

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, dosbox

I've recently started writing assembly procedures. My problem is I don't know how to end a procedure. I wrote the code below which didn't display the desired output until I added
 `jmp finish` 
after the second function call. I don't understand why the program doesn't go to finish on it's own. I'd really appreciate your explanation.

```
            Data_segment_name segment para

            Data_segment_name ends


            Stack_segment_name segment para stack
            dw 16 dup(0)             ;define your stack segment
            Stack_segment_name ends


            Code_segment_name segment
            Main_prog proc far

            assume SS:Stack_segment_name,CS:Code_segment_name,DS:Data_segment_name

            mov AX,Data_segment_name  ;load the starting address of the data
            mov DS,AX                 ; segment into DS reg.

            call cls
            call draw1
            ;jmp finish
            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            cls proc near
            mov ax,0b800h
            mov es,ax
            mov ax,0720h
            mov di,0
            mov cx,2000
            rep stosw 
            ret
            cls endp
            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            draw1 proc near       
            push ax

            mov di,160*9+40*2 
            mov ax,0b800h
            mov es,ax
            mov ax, 1f2ah             
            stosw
            cld


            pop ax
            ret
            draw1 endp

            finish:
            mov ax,4c00h ; exit program
            int 21h
            Main_prog endp
            Code_segment_name ends
            end Main_prog
```

Comment: You nested your procedures into `Main_prog`, that's why. You should move up the 4 lines starting with `finish:` to the `jmp finish`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I have another question though,how can I write my procedures without nesting them into the far procedure? @jester

Comment: Told you how. Move the ending including the `Main_prog endp` up.

Comment: Yes I did so and it worked. I was just wondering if I can remove the whole Main_prog and just write my procedures and call them but I don't think that'll work. Thanks anyway. @jester

Comment: I don't think you need a main procedure, but you'd still need an entry point label.

Comment: While you may feel that you have logically organized your code into separate "modules," when assembled it will be linearly arranged in memory.  This means that your functions or procedures are sitting right in the middle of your "main."

Answer (score 0):

probably the best solution would be to put the `finish` code in the main module itself, so you set up initial values, call subroutines, and exit, all from the main module.

otherwise your code would just "fall through" from the main module into the subroutines and get lost, or segfault, when the first subroutine "returns".

Comment: I moved the 4 lines starting with finish: to the jmp finish like @jester said. That worked for me

Comment: so please "answer" the question with what you did. not in a comment. thanks.